# can a const function be recursive in C++ , as long as it modies mutable variables?

Tags: c++

Can i have a const function that is recursive in my class ?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself first? How much efforts it needs?

Comment: @Nawaz: "It works for me" and "well defined behaviour" are very hard to distinguish

Comment: @awoodland: You've a point. but then from the title it seems he didn't even try, otherwise the title should be like *"is this well defined if I...."*

Comment: Remember that a const function can modify variables local to the function without breaking the "const" contract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. `const` can always call `const` functions again. You don't even need mutable variables for it to make sense, for example you can pass things by reference into the recursive function and modify those for your state. (Or static variables, or non-members, or other functions which return non-const references or pointers to non-const things....)

Minimal "useful" example (inspired by flownt's comment on the other answer) traversing a linked list. (Recursion isn't a great way of doing linked list traversal normally though)

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Item {
public:
  Item(const int& in, Item *next=NULL) : value(in), next(next) {}
  void sum(int& result) const {
     result += value;
     if (next.get())
        next->sum(result);
  }
private: 
  int value;
  std::auto_ptr<Item> next;
};

int main() {
  Item i(5, new Item(10, new Item(20)));
  int result = 0;
  i.sum(result);
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

You can also avoid the using the reference for the result, as appropriate for your problem, by re-writing `sum()`:

```
  int sum() const {
     return value + (next.get() ? next->sum() : 0);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure! For example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  int Factorial(int x)const
  {
    return x==1 ? 1 : x*Factorial(x-1);
  }
}
```

You can only call const functions on the class, but other than that there's no restriction!

Comment: though one would never use this function, since it uses no state from foo... a better example of a use is a search in a binary search tree, which is a non-mutating operation and is most easily implemented using recursion.

Comment: @flownt: I know, it's just meant to illustrate that const methods can be recursive :-)